# Error re-installing grub: windows partition corrupted?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, grub

I am a Linux newbie, had Windows XP and Ubuntu installed (9.10/ grub2) and working perfectly. I had to re-install Windows XP and thus I followed the official tutorial to reinstall grub2 (and run update-grub2). I don't know if I made an mistake but:
 - grub is working on startup, listing Ubuntu and XP (OK)
 - when I select Windows XP I just get a black screen (Not OK)
 - when I boot on a Win XP CD, it doesn't detect any hard drive (Ugh)

I guess there is some problem with the file system of my windows partition? Here is the output of

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

(Win XP is supposed to be on /dev/sda1 and my documents are saved on /dev/sda5)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes  
240 heads, 63 sectors/track, 10337 cylinders  
Units = cylinders of 15120 * 512 = 7741440 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0xcccdcccd  


Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System  
/dev/sda1 * 1 4741 35841928+ 7 HPFS/NTFS  
/dev/sda2 4742 10338 42306202 f W95 Ext'd (LBA)  
/dev/sda5 4742 7427 20303544 7 HPFS/NTFS  
/dev/sda6 10210 10338 963868+ 82 Linux swap / Solaris  
/dev/sda7 7427 10210 21038080 83 Linux  


Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Matt

Comment: As a note, I can say that you probably have a SATA harddisk (they're represented as sdX, ATA ones are hdX), and Windows XP default installation disk doesn't include drivers for SATA chipsets.